# Use of undeclared identifier PhonesViewController ios7 xCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7, addressbook

Can you please help me with this error that I'am getting...
Basically, I'm trying to import all my contact list from my address book. Also I'm checking the phone number label, but the error that I'm getting is  "Use of undeclared identifier PhonesViewController ios7 xCode" and I have that viewController, and also I have added the class in storyboard for the viewcontroller although I think that it is not necessary 
Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```
#import "PhonesViewController.h"

@implementation PhonesViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    - (BOOL)PhohesViewController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)picker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
    {
        // Name of contact.

        NSString* name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);

        // Numbers of selected contact

        ABMutableMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

        NSMutableString *mobile = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        NSMutableString *office = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

        // Getting if Mobile, Office(work) numbers exist

        for(CFIndex numberIndex = 0; numberIndex < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); numberIndex++)
        {
            // Number in contact details of current index

            CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, numberIndex);

            // Label of Phone Number

            CFStringRef locLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, numberIndex);
            NSString *phoneLabel =(NSString*) ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locLabel);

            // Phone number

            NSString *phoneNumber = (NSString *)phoneNumberRef;

            // Release Phone Number and locationLabel reference object

            CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);
            CFRelease(locLabel);

            NSLog(@"  - %@ (%@)", phoneNumber, phoneLabel);

            if ([phoneLabel isEqualToString:@"mobile"])// Mobile number saving.
            {
                [mobile appendFormat:@"%@", phoneNumber];
            }
            else if ([phoneLabel isEqualToString:@"work"])// Office number saving.
            {
                [office appendFormat:@"%@", phoneNumber];
            }

            [phoneNumber release];
        }
        CFRelease(phones);

        // Emails of selected contact

        ABMutableMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);

        NSMutableString *generalMail = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        NSMutableString *officeMail = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

        // Getting if Home, Office(work) mails exist

        for(CFIndex numberIndex = 0; numberIndex < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); numberIndex++)
        {
            // Mail in contact details of current index

            CFStringRef mailRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, numberIndex);

            // Label of Phone Number

            CFStringRef locLabel = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emails, numberIndex);
            NSString *mailLabel =(NSString*) ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locLabel);

            // Phone number

            NSString *mail = (NSString *)mailRef;

            // Release Phone Number and locationLabel reference object

            CFRelease(mailRef);
            CFRelease(locLabel);
            NSLog(@"  - %@ (%@)", mail, mailLabel);

            if ([mailLabel isEqualToString:@"mobile"])// Home mail.
            {
                [generalMail appendFormat:@"%@", mail];
            }
            else if ([mailLabel isEqualToString:@"work"])// Office(Work) mail.
            {
                [officeMail appendFormat:@"%@", mail];
            }

            [mail release];
        }
        CFRelease(emails);

        [mobile release];
        [office release];

        [generalMail release];
        [officeMail release];

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        return NO;
    }

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo to me.

```
// Phohes?
- (BOOL)PhohesViewController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)picker //Phohes? shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
```

Comment: It's not a typo..
[link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=11si33r&s=8#.VFftQvTF_ZU)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code and the image you've posted, you're defining a method within a method, you can't do that.